# SQL Start + End Date with daily interval

Tags: postgresql

I have a start date like 2015-07-01 and end date of 2015-07-06. I want my query to run in a interval of 1 day and return result:

```
2015-07-01
2015-07-02
2015-07-03
... etc to 2015-07-06
```

Using the current interval date in the query for looking.

Using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgresql has a generate_series funciton that does this

```
select generate_series('2015-07-01'::date,' 2015-07-06'::date,'1 day');
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/1406)